# How to Create SELECT for Total sales for each region

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I want to write a query to get Total sales for every region, but i cant figure the way to do it. I have these tables:

```
Region(RegionID, Name)
Client(ClientID, Name, City, Country, Email, RegionID)
Order(OrderID, Orderdate, ClientID)
Orderdetail(OrderID, ProductID, Quantityordered, Quantitydelivered)
Product(ProductID, Name, UnitPrice)
```

Comment: join your tables together first (did you try/get that to work)?  then sum and group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First join all the tables, and sum the quantity.
Try this:

```
    SELECT r.Name AS RegionName, TotalQuantityOrdered = SUM(od.Quantityordered), TotalQuantityDelivered = SUM(Quantitydelivered) 
    FROM Orderdetail od
    INNER JOIN Order o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    Inner join Client c on o.ClientID = c.ClientID
    Inner Join Region r on c.RegionId = r.RegionId
    Group By r.Name
```

Comment: @Urago, we are welcome, if this works, can you please tick on 'This answer is useful'.